# Interactive network sniffing

Tags: networking, firewall, wireshark, sniffing

I'm looking for what essentially amounts to an "interactive" [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org).

I am looking for a tool that allows me to view network traffic on a given port and allow/deny/modify traffic on a per-packet basis. Ideally, the tool could be scripted as there might be a substantial volume of traffic.

It seems that [Paros](http://www.parosproxy.org/) might fit the bill, but it is restricted to HTTP only; I would prefer a tool that is protocol-agnostic. [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) would be a better fit, but arguably affords *too* much flexibility -- is there a pretty GUI for it that fits my use case?

Does such a tool exist or shall I have to roll my own?

Comment: You should roll your own and sell the damned thing; there's got to be a market for this.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case it's only for web browser traffic after all (I know you prefer otherwise), and you're on Windows: [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/)?

> Fiddler is a Web Debugging Proxy which logs all HTTP(S) traffic between your computer and the Internet. Fiddler allows you to inspect all HTTP(S) traffic, set breakpoints, and "fiddle" with incoming or outgoing data. Fiddler includes a powerful event-based scripting subsystem, and can be extended using any .NET language.

For a Mac: [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) does kind of the same, but is not free.